# jQuery ajax - trying to catch error -G is undefined

Tags: jquery, json

So my server side script returns the folloiwing json key/value pair on error:

```
{"error":"true"}
```

I see this via firebug.
Within my script I have

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  data:{
    foo: $('#foo').val()
  },
  url: "index.pl",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function( data ){
    //this part all works fine
  },
  error: function( data ){
    alert('Error returned from server');
  }
});
```

I get an error:

```
G is undefined
```

Followed by the packed string of jquery.min.

if it matters I'm on jquery 1.3.2.min.js.

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Fixed typo

Comment: is your xml name really foo@?

Comment: Sorry, no, a typo, my mistake. Thank you

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: There's *another* syntax error in your quoted code in addition to the `foo@:` one you just fixed (there's a missing comma after `"json"`). Please use **copy and paste** to put code in questions, to avoid wasting people's time and to make sure your actual issue gets addressed.

Comment: The obvious question is: Does `index.pl` really respond to the ajax call with JSON? The name suggests that it's a landing page, which would respond with HTML.

Comment: yeah, the json returned from the page is shown in firebug as described.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry, different computers on different networks, locked down so they can't communicate. Typos fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my mistake was in a misunderstanding of the jQuery ajax, specifically error. This relates to bad connection, timeout 500 errors, not to returning something via json like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error you have is in your JSON response. You're getting a string (`"true"`). Are you sure you don't need a boolean? If so, your JSON should be:

```
{"error":true}
```

Hope it helps!